AWS: Binding CDK Alarms with Powertools metrics

Powertools docs
CDK Alarm docs

I'm trying to use CDK to create an Alarm from metrics created by Powertools. This seems like it should be a fairly common use-case, but I'm missing something conceptually.
My understanding is that these two different "runtimes" are connected via the namespace, metricName, and possibly the dimensionMap and so, therefore, have some constants that I'm using to connect them. Here's snippets
// Lambda code
import { Metrics, MetricUnit } from "@aws-lambda-powertools/metrics";

const metrics = new Metrics({
  namespace: NAMESPACE,
  serviceName: SERVICE_NAME,
});

metrics.addMetric(
    METRIC_NAME,
    MetricUnit.Count,
    datapoints.length
);

// CDK code
import { Alarm, Metric } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudwatch";

const missingRDAlarm = new Alarm(this, "MissingRequestDescriptionAlarm", {
      metric: new Metric({
        namespace: NAMESPACE,
        metricName: METRIC_NAME,
        period: Duration.minutes(5),
        statistic: "Sum",
        dimensionsMap: { service: SERVICE_NAME },
      }),
      threshold: 1,
      evaluationPeriods: 1,
});

The result is that both the metric and the alarm get created, but are not related. Is this the wrong approach? Is there something simple I'm missing?
